# Golf a Sentence

Tags: code-golf, string

Everybody loves golfing code. Code is written in English (eh...). Therefore, everybody loves golfing English!

Your task is to write a program or function that takes a string as input, and then returns or prints the golfed version. There will be no newlines or tabs in the input.

This is how you golf a string. The order matters!

1. Remove spaces directly before and after punctuation: `"Hey there", he said   ; he ' s a cat. -> "Hey there",he said;he's a cat.` The following count as punctuation: `.,?!"':;()`
2. Replace `he/she/it is`, case insensitive, with `he's/she's/it's`: `It is unfortunate that she is not coming ever. -> It's unfortunate that she's not coming ever.`
3. Words that start with capital letters in a sentence can be moved against the preceding word (omitting the space): `The farmer told Fred that he should leave. -> The farmer toldFred that he should leave.`
4. Trailing and leading spaces should be removed: `[      ]It's raining.[     ]-> It's raining.` Ignore the brackets (annoying auto-formatting).
5. Remove repeated punctuation *that is the same*: `""Here''s the cake",, said Fred..! -> "Here's the cake",saidFred.!`

If we were to golf the first paragraph of this challenge, the output would be:

> Everybody loves golfing code.Code is written inEnglish(eh.).Therefore,everybody loves golfingEnglish!

This is code golf––or rather English golf––so shortest code in bytes wins!

**Here is one all encompassing test case:**

Input: `"    You are crazy"",, , , she said. It is unfortunate that Margaret had to say that... she is a Martian!.`

Output: `"You are crazy",she said.It's unfortunate thatMargaret had to say that.she's aMartian!.`

Comment: `inEnglish(eh.)`. You collapsed the space between parentheses and text, though you don't explicitly count parens as punctuation.

Comment: Does "whitespace" mean all whitespace or just spaces? (i.e. does it include newlines, tabs, etc.)

Comment: @Downgoat. Whitespace is just spaces. There are no new lines or tabs in the input. I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: Why should the `He is` in `He is here` remain unchanged?

Comment: @Dopapp Ok, well then, in that case, you should change the rule back to what it used to be. It makes no sense that `She is` and `It is` become `She's` and `It's` respectively, but `He is` does not become `He's`.

Comment: @Dopapp Well, that is not what Rule # 2 implies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42231/discussion-between-dopapp-and-r-kap).

Comment: I suggest adding tests cases that encompass all the rules and edge cases to avoid answers that miss some edge cases

Comment: @Downgoat, I added an all encompassing test case.

Comment: @Dopapp in that test case, why is "that.she is aMartian!." not "that.she's aMartian!."

Comment: @Downgoat, oh I didn't catch that!

Comment: @Dopapp Initially, There were lot's of things I didn't have to handle that you added in the middle. It's frustrating to have to accompany rules that are constantly changing and not very clear. At this point, I'd rather just delete my answer than keep updating it. I'm not suggesting you change it back (that would just make it worse).

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan, I truly am terribly sorry. In an effort to clear up the question and accommodate all of the answers, it seems that I just made it worse. I promise you now that the rules are now set in stone and no further changes will be made to them.

Comment: What characters would the input contain?

Comment: @LeakyNun, any ASCII characters.

Comment: @Dopapp Then that is not "one all encompassing test case".

Comment: @LeakyNun, it is all encompassing for the rules. Every rule is tested in the test case.

Comment: Does rule 5 mean that `@@` should become `@`?

Comment: @LeakyNun, No because @ is not part of the defined punctuation set defined in rule 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Retina, 65 bytes

```
+` *([.,?!"':;()])\1* *| ([A-Z])| +$|^ +
$1$2
i`(s?he|it) is
$1's
```

Regex replacement and then a simple trim

The magic regex is:

```
 *([.,?!"':;()])\1* *| ([A-Z])| +$|^ +
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2AgKihbLiw_ISInOjsoKV0pXDEqICp8IChbQS1aXSkKJDEkMgogKyR8XiArCgppYChzP2hlfGl0KSBpcwokMSdz&input=IiAgICBZb3UgYXJlIGNyYXp5IiIsLCAsICwgc2hlIHNhaWQuIEl0IGlzIHVuZm9ydHVuYXRlIHRoYXQgTWFyZ2FyZXQgaGFkIHRvIHNheSB0aGF0Li4uIHNoZSBpcyBhIE1hcnRpYW4hLg)

Answer (score 3):

## V, 77 bytes

```
Ó *¨[.,"':;?!()]© */±
Óã¨s¿heüit©ús is/'s
Óó«úeõ
Ó^ *ü *$
Ó¨[.,"':;?!()]©±*/±
```

Way longer than I'd like.

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w5MgKsKoWy4sIic6Oz8hKCldwqkgKi_CsQrDk8Ojwqhzwr9oZcO8aXTCqcO6cyBpcy8ncwrDk8OzwqvDumXDtQrDk14gKsO8ICokCsOTwqhbLiwiJzo7PyEoKV3CqcKxKi_CsQ&input=IiAgICBZb3UgYXJlIGNyYXp5IiIsLCAsICwgc2hlIHNhaWQuIEl0IGlzIHVuZm9ydHVuYXRlIHRoYXQgTWFyZ2FyZXQgaGFkIHRvIHNheSB0aGF0Li4uIHNoZSBpcyBhIE1hcnRpYW4hLgoiWW91IGFyZSBjcmF6eSIsc2hlIHNhaWQuSXQncyB1bmZvcnR1bmF0ZSB0aGF0TWFyZ2FyZXQgaGFkIHRvIHNheSB0aGF0LnNoZSdzIGFNYXJ0aWFuIS4)

Comment: V is new retina? (can you add explanation)

Comment: Eventually. This is a longer one so it might take a while to write out...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>102</s> <s>92</s> <s>61</s> <s>65</s> 95 bytes

```
x=>x.replace(/ *([.,?!"':;()])( *\1 *)*| ([A-Z])/g,"$1$3").replace(/(he|it) is/g,"$1's").trim()
```

Works on the last testcase. Saved a lot of bytes thanks to Downgoat! Impressive.

Comment: `x[R="replace"](/ *([.,?!"':;()]) */g,"$1")[R](/ ([A-Z])/g,"$1")` -> `x[R="replace"](/ *([.,?!"':;()]) *| ([A-Z])/g,"$1$2")`

Comment: @Downgoat I tried that earlier, but that didn't work for me XD works now tho

Comment: Make the first regex `/ *([.,?!"':;()])\1* *| ([A-Z])/g` and the you should be able to remove the other prelace

Comment: To fix bugs with `hello, , ,` you're gonna have to make it: `x=>x.replace(/ *([.,?!"':;()])( *\1 *)*| ([A-Z])/g,"$1$3").trim()` at 65 bytes. I'll see if I can golf it more

Comment: @Dopapp... in your console, maybe?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ you could use esfiddle: http://vihan.org/p/esfiddle/

Comment: This doesn't do anything for 'he she it'.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan I thought the OP said rule #2 was "anulled" ?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ, I am so terribly sorry. Someone in the comments confused me a little with the wording and I went a little crazy. Now the rules are set in stone.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, 213 bytes:

```
import re;R=re.sub;W=lambda G:G.group(0);print(R(r'(\W)\1+',lambda f:W(f)[0],R('\s*[^\s\w]\s*|\s*[A-Z]',lambda f:W(f).strip(),R('((I|i)t|(s|S)?(h|H)e) is',lambda i:W(i)[:[*W(i)].index(" ")]+"'s",input().strip()))))
```

Uses 3 regular expressions in a row with `re.sub` in conjunction with Python's `str.strip()` built in to golf the input English sentence.

[Try It Online! (repl.it)](https://repl.it/CaJg/1)

Answer (score 0):

## <s>Bash 74</s> Sed 65 + 4 bytes

65 bytes for the script and 4 for the `r` and `f` flags.

<s>`sed -r "s/\s*([.,?\!\"\':;\(\)A-Z])(\1|\s)*/\1/g;s/(he|she|it) is/\1\'s/i"`</s>
`s/\s*([,.?\!\"\':;\(\)A-Z])(\1|\s)*/\1/g;s/(he|she|it) is/\1\'s/i`

Usage: Enter text, press enter and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (send EOF).